# xmltodict throwing errors when used in a .py file

Tags: python, xmltodict

I want to get xmltodict in python2.7 up and running for a project I have, so I started by copy-pasting from the only example I was able to find

```
import xmltodict

with open ('test.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

print doc
```

Trying to run this results in the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'

Same thing when trying to convert a dict to xml using the xmltodict.unparse function.

However, it works if I do this line by line in IDLE... Any idea why this fails when trying to run it in a .py file, but works when I use the interpreter line by line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't name your script `xmltodict.py`. It is [getting imported](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) instead of an installed into the Python environment `xmltodict` package.

Comment: My script was called xml.py, not xmltodict.py. Renaming it 'test.py' did not change the error.

Comment: @KBriggs look for other scripts named `xmltodict` then. What is the value of `xmltodict.__file__` when you import it in your script? Thanks.

Comment: I deleted xml.py and suddenly test.py worked. Apparently importing xmltodict was also importing xml.py? Maybe there is an import internal to xmltodict that imports xml.py and breaks everything.

Comment: So I guess the lesson here is "don't name your scripts anything vaguely related to the packages you are importing just on the off chance you duplicate something"